# SharePoint Search Overriding Crawl Rules

Tags: search, crawling, crawl-rules

Is there a way to override a crawl rule in SharePoint 2007 Central Admin?  For example, if I have a site and I only want users to see content from http://www.mysite.com/sites/portal in search results, can I block the development and staging sites like so:

Exclude http://www.mysite.com/sites/* -- this will exclude .../sites/dev and .../sites/staging

Include: http://www.mysite.com/sites/portal -- will this be included?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I implemented the rule set above and tried to use the built-in test function and results  indicated that the portal site would **not** be included.  Not sure if that's truly the case but still curious if this is actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've just found out it will work if you use the "correct" order, that is, put the url you want in first, and then exclude the other stuff. Therefore:

```
(order=1) Include: http://www.mysite.com/sites/portal 
(order=2) Exclude: http://www.mysite.com/sites/* -- this will exclude .../sites/dev and .../sites/staging
```

Will make the test for *http://www.mysite.com/sites/portal* pass

Unfortunately it is still ignored by the crawler!